# Vue JS display table row once

Tags: vue.js

I'm unable to figure out how to loop through the array in the code I'm working on.

I want the table row to display once not thrice.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    a: {
      b:[
          { c: [ {d: "1"}, {d: "2"}, {d: "3"} ] },
          { c: [ {d: "1"}, {d: "2"}, {d: "3"} ] },
          { c: [ {d: "1"}, {d: "2"}, {d: "3"} ] }
        ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr v-for="b in a.b">
      <th v-for="c in b.c">{{c.d}}
        
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xe8w1q4u/

Comment: `a.b` is an array with three element. So `v-for="b in a.b"` will loop three times. What are you expecting/trying to achieve?

Comment: I am well aware of that. I want the table row to display once not thrice - as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Then why are you using `v-for` ?

Comment: Damn, I was not thinking straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you just want to display the first row:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    a: {
      b:[
          { c: [ {d: "1"}, {d: "2"}, {d: "3"} ] },
          { c: [ {d: "1"}, {d: "2"}, {d: "3"} ] },
          { c: [ {d: "1"}, {d: "2"}, {d: "3"} ] }
        ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr v-if="a.b.length > 0">
      <th v-for="c in a.b[0].c">
        {{c.d}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```